# find all the matrices (which are not similiar) which fulfill this formula

Tags: jordan-normal-form, minimal-polynomials, characteristic-polynomial, cayley-hamilton, similar-matrices

I need to find all the matrices $A\in M_{4x4}\left(\mathbb{C}\right)\:$ such that:

$$A^4-2A^2+I\:=\:0$$

which means $\left(A^2-I\right)^2=0$

So I see that there is a few groups of which can give this result:

1. matrices which $\left(A^2-I\right)=0$
2. matrices which $\left(A^2-I\right)!=0$ but $\left(A^2-I\right)^2=0$

But I still don't see how to find them explicitly and generally, although I can write some matrices of the first case which fit in, and for the second group its is harder.

Does anyone see how can I generalize the solution using some knowledge about characteristic polynomial, minimal polynomial, eigenvalues (1,-1) to find all the not similar matrices which fit the formula ?

Comment: Upper triangular (lower triangular also) matrices with only 1 or $- 1$ on diagonal are the matrices which surely satisfy the conditions you have given.

Comment: ok, according to Cayley Hamilton Theorem, this is the characteristic polynomial. 
I can take a general form matrix 4*4, and do the math but it is many calculations, and I think there is a shortcut. 
Ok, you named a few groups of matrices which satisfy the formula, but a general solution for all of them ?
I need to find all the matrices who's characteristic polynomial is this, and the minimal polynomial can be the same or one order lower. How do I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

You have $p(A) = 0$ where $p(x) = (x-1)^2(x+1)^2$.

According to [Jordan normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) or [Lemme des noyaux](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemme_des_noyaux) (sorry this in in French...), the matrix $A$ is similar to a matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}
A_1 & 0\\
0 & A_{-1}\end{pmatrix}$$ where $\dim A_1 = \dim \ker p_1(A)$, $\dim A_{-1} = \dim \ker p_{-1}(A)$, $p_1(A_1) = 0$, $p_{-1}(A_{-1}) = 0$ where $p_1(x) = (x-1)^2$ and $p_{-1}(x)=(x+1)^2$.

Finally, this provides all the matrices similar to one of the matrices

$$\begin{pmatrix}
\epsilon_1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & \epsilon_2 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & \epsilon_3 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \epsilon_4\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
\epsilon_1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & \epsilon_1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & \epsilon_2 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \epsilon_3\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
\epsilon_1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & \epsilon_1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & \epsilon_2 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \epsilon_2\end{pmatrix}
$$

where $\epsilon_i \in \{-1,1\}$.

If you don't know the theorems mentioned above, you can mimic their demonstration to your special case.